# define a namespace across multiple files

Tags: c++, file, namespaces

I wanna declare a single namespace (let's say "Mynamespace")across multiple files like namespace "std" it is declared across multiple header files like "iostream" and "array" and "vector" etc ...(I declared them in two header files only )

how can I do that ?

Comment: Just declare the namespace in the files, and remember to put declarations of the namespace in the header files.

Comment: Just do it, it works just as one would expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each file you do the namespace declaration as usual. No tricks needed.

A namespace is not like a class, you can add to is as you see fit.

Or as Andrew Hare succinctly says in the duplicate:

> Yes, that is exactly how to do it.

Comment: did work here are my file :

Comment: @MekacherAnis I don't understand your comment.

Comment: I declared two different variables in the same namespace in two header files only  ,what is the a problem ?